# Логическое удаление в базе данных

Tags: ado, delphi-7

Есть БД (подключение ado),  есть функция логического удаления(фильтрация),  все работает,  но когда пытаюсь удалить последнюю запись, выдает ошибку:

> class EOleException with message 'BOF или EOF имеет значение true, либо текущая запись удалена, для выполняемой операции требуется требуется текущая запись'

Код кнопки:

```
inc(c_max);

if DataModule1.TableClient.FieldByName('FIO').AsString = '' then
  exit;

DataModule1.TableClient.Edit;
DataModule1.TableClient.FieldByName('Del').AsInteger := c_max;
DataModule1.TableClient.Post;
DataModule1.TableClient.Filter := 'Del=0';
DataModule1.TableClient.Filtered := true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не совсем корректно проверяете вот тут

```
if DataModule1.TableClient.FieldByName('FIO').AsString = '' then
exit;
```

Это и вызывает ошибку, так как записей не осталось и обращаться тупо не к чему. а вы пытаетесь у пустоты узнать фамилию.

Более корректно тут будет проверять на флаг EoF или же на крайний случай - количество записей в выборке. Эти действия не будут вызывать исключение даже если выборка не содержит ни 1 записи.

Comment: ошибка возникает в строке    

DataModule1.TableClient.Post;

Comment: Опишите подробнее что происходит с вашими данными вот тут
DataModule1.TableClient.Edit;

На Delphi уже достаточно давно не писал.

Comment: таблица открывается на редактирование

Comment: Замечательно. а вы уверены что вам есть что редактировать? Если записей не осталось то вы получите ту самую ошибку.

Вспомнил этот механизм. ИМХО понятнее и проще написать нормальные запросы чем работать с таблицей напрямую. Хотя опять же. По такому куску кода полную задачу не определить.

Comment: конечно есть - последняя запись еще активна, когда я жму на кнопку